# Python regular expression replace date

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have string like this

**INPUT:**

```
date = '2017-02-03 14:07:03.840'
```

And how replace `2017-02-03` In order to on output I'll have

```
2017-02-03 14:07:03.840 => 2015-01-01 14:07:03.840
```

How to replace only date without time? Using **re** module

Comment: `\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following *regex* to select only the date and by substituting it with your desired date you can get the expected result :

```
\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}
```

**python**

```
import re
regex = r"\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}"
date = "2017-02-03 14:07:03.840"
subst = "2015-01-01"
result = re.sub(regex, subst, date, 0)
if result:
    print (result)
```

Comment: How I can replace time in the new string? **14:07:03.840**

Comment: @Maic use this *regex* `\d+:\d+:[\d.]+`